# Get 401 Unauthorized when call web api even if I enable Anonymous Authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401

I am developing a web api. When I ran web api in local workstation by Visual Studio and used Fiddler or IE to consume it, all things were fine. 
But if I deployed it into a remote IIS server, I get 401 error code in IE, Fiddler or client application. Even I enable Anonymous Authentication in IIS, 401 still occurs. 
Could anyone give me some suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: DO you have disabled all other authentication? Try disabling all other authentication except Anonymous for the Website/WebApplication in IIS.

Comment: 401 still occurs even all other authentication disabled.

Comment: What authentication(s) is the server's `WWW-Authenticate` response header actually asking for?

Comment: I don't set WWW-Authenticate anything.

Comment: Your webApp has Application User(pass through authentication) or Specific User? Make your IIS is able to access physical location & that is never shared to anybody, this sometimes causes problems...

Answer (score 1):

You can right click in the **Authentification** the **"Anonymous Authentification"** and select **Edit**. From there, you can assign on which credential you run the **Anonymous authentification**. If you set your own account, it should work (or any account that can run the web api).